# How to create an auto fill field in word document that updates based on the content of the first instance

Tags: vba, ms-word, autofill

I have a word document where I have some text that is intentionally repeated; let's say, "This is my text". For each of the later instances of "This is my text" in the document, I would like any changes in the **first** instance to auto-populate into all the other instances. So it should follow this process.

1. Initially, the text says, "This is my text".
2. I change the first instance "This is my text" to "This is my new text".
3. Each of the later instances automatically changes to match the change.

I already looked into these two guides ([1](https://www.howtogeek.com/502179/how-to-create-and-use-autotext-entries-in-word/), [2](https://www.teachucomp.com/create-building-blocks-in-word-instructions/#:%7E:text=Create%20Building%20Blocks%20in%20Word%3A%20Instructions%201%20To,future.%20...%2012%20Finally%2C%20click%20the%20%E2%80%9COK%E2%80%9D%20button.)), but they aren't what I was looking to do.

Is this possible to do with a relatively simple macro? I have no experience with macros in word, so this would be my first time doing something like this.

Comment: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/repeating_data.html

Comment: @TimWilliams looks like this has potential, thanks. I'll check it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: This is what MS created content controls for. Ignore the page suggested by Tim Williams as this approach is now outdated and instead take a look at the pages on content controls, particularly [mapped content controls](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html)

Comment: OK so I got it to work, but every time I save the document the quick-part fields revert back. Is there something I'm doing wrong?